# How do I allow POST to a list_route, but not to the entire ViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-method

I have a `Game` model and am doing the corresponding REST routes for it, e.g. `GET /game`, `GET /game/1`, etc.

I only want API consumers to GET existing games. I don't want them to be able to POST new games arbitrarily. Rather, they should have to go through a specal route, `POST /game/upload_schedule` for this.

I have the following:

```
class GameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def upload_schedule(self, request):
        return Response(["foo"])
```

However, when I `POST /game/upload_schedule`, I get a method not allowed error. The reason is that `http_method_names` prevents it from happening. If I change it to the following:

```
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'post']
```

Then the `POST /game/upload_schedule` route works. However, now so does `POST /game`!

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

This is an XY Problem. The `GameViewSet` should only deal with `Game`s and things specifically dealing with games. Uploading the schedule is not a property of a list of games - it is a separate route. So, make it an `APIView`, separate from the `GameViewSet`:

```
class UploadSchedule(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

And then route it up explicitly under `^upload_schedule$`.